# How do I translate my angular app with minimal watch impact?

Tags: angularjs, localization

How do I translate my angular app with minimal watch impact?

Here's what I'm thinking (but anything that meets the watch impact criteria I'm ears for) - is there an existing library that takes `.html` files as an input, extracts the strings that need to be translated into a template (ideally a `.resx` file, but any format with key/value/comment can be converted into a resource file), which can be translated by hand/outsourcing, and then this same library takes the localized templates and original input `.html` files and generates localized `.html` files?  That's the only way I can think to do localization without generating additional watches for each translated phrase.  (Of course I can write this myself, but I make it a habit to prefer a community-supported solutions to my more-error-prone-by-myself-libraries.)

It's safe for me to assume that the user will not change his or her locale preference at run-time (being able to change languages at run time is the only advantage I see by having watches introduced by translating directives and filters in libraries like angular-translate and angular-gettext).

Having typed that out, a library *could* use interpolation and filters, have the localiztion specified in a `.config()` block and then have the watches fire only once.  That would be acceptable.

Comment: This *might* be premature optimization. Are you currently experiencing a performance issue? Or are you worried about one that doesn't yet exist?

Comment: Yes we are currently experiencing slowness on slower VM's.  It's at approximately 2.5k - 3k watches already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a library which can reduce the watch impact and that is [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) and then you can find a demo at [plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jwrHVb?p=preview)

The BindOnce can be used like this:

```
        <tr bindonce ng-repeat="person in Persons" bo-class="            {'male':person.gender=='M','female':person.gender=='F'}">
            <td bo-bind="$index + 1"></td>
            <td><img bo-src="person.picture" /></td>
            <td bo-bind="person.firstname"></td>
            <td bo-bind="person.lastname"></td>
            <!-- BAD PRACTICE FOR STYLE ON PURPOSE: Using a function as binder is not good -->
            <td><span bo-bind="person.age" bo-style="ageColor(person.age)" style=""></span></td>
            <td bo-bind="person.gender"></td>
            <td>
                <a bo-href="person.url">
                    <spam bo-bind="(person.url)?'link':'missing'" bo-class="{'label label-important':!person.url}"></spam>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I was aware of bindonce.  The problem is the localization library needs to use bindonce.  Do you know of any?  Thanks!